# React application architecture: how to pass events upwards in deep hierarchy

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a hierarchy of react components:

```
<Parent>
   <Child>
      <GrandChild>
        <GrandGrandChild />
      </GrandChild>
   </Child>
</Parent>
```

Now `GrandGrandChild` triggers an event that shall be handled by `Parent`. How do I get the information across the hieararchy? I can think of two ways:

#### Alternative 1:

Parent.render:

```
<div><Child onMyEvent={this.handler.bind(this)} /></div>
```

Child.render:

```
<div><GrandChild onMyEvent={this.props.onMyEvent} /></div>
```

GrandChild.render:

```
<div><GrandGrandChild onMyEvent={this.props.onMyEvent} /></div>
```

When the event occurs, GrandGrandChild will call

```
this.props.onMyEvent(args)
```

#### Alternative 2:

Parent.render:

```
<div><Child app={this} /></div>
```

Child.render:

```
<div><GrandChild app={this.props.app} /></div>
```

GrandChild.render:

```
<div><GrandGrandChild app={this.props.app} /></div>
```

When the event occurs, GrandGrandChild will call

```
this.props.app.onMyEvent.bind(this.props.app)(args)
```

Both alternatives require passing a prop through all levels. What is better? Or is there an even better alternative?

Comment: Another alternative is some type of flux action (redux actions, for example).

Comment: I've used both of those strategies and at the end of the day and I would recommend switching to use some type of state management ala flux / redux. Passing props through many children inevitably becomes a cluttered mess and is a huge pain to refactor

Comment: **Here (might) be dragons.** I second what Davin and Jon have said, but just for the sake of completeness: another alternative could be to use [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Comment: That's where a state container comes into play (Flux, Redux, MobX). When you start to have complex state using one of these state containers will simplify managing and passing this state. Otherwise the approaches you're displaying above are the only ways to pass state/props down the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `redux` and it solved the problem (any connected components can access any part of the application state without having to pass props through multiple levels of components). Managing state with reducer functions is a bit more work than with `setState` but if you observe some best practice, it pays off.